# String in one Excel cell, Read and pass as argument to a method

Tags: c#, excel

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace Something
{
[TestClass]
public class CBMain:Base
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {

            string ExcelFilePath = "D:\\Excel.xlsx";
            Excel.Application exlApp;
            Excel.Workbook exlWorkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet exlWorkSheet;
            Excel.Range exlRange;

            exlApp = new Excel.Application();
            exlWorkBook = exlApp.Workbooks.Open(@ExcelFilePath);
            exlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)exlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            exlRange = exlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

            int exlRowCount = exlRange.Rows.Count;
            int exlColumnCount = exlRange.Columns.Count;

            int rcount = 1, ccount = 1;
            for (rcount = 3; rcount <= exlRowCount; rcount++)
            {

                string[] ExcelToMethod1 = (exlRange.Cells[rcount, (ccount + 8)] as Excel.Range).Value2;

                string[] ExcelToMethod1 = (exlRange.Cells[rcount, (ccount + 10)] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                Console.WriteLine(ExcelToMethod1 + " | " + ExcelToMethod1 );

                //**Calling method for creating program
                ClassName Program = new ClassName();
                Program.MethodCall(ExcelToMethod1 ,ExcelToMethod2);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        //Console.WriteLine(exlRowCount);
        //Console.WriteLine(exlColumnCount);
    }
}
}
```

I want to read values from Excel sheet and pass them as arguments in a method. 
In Excel the values are stored as `{"Var1","Var2","Var3"}` in one cell. So when I am trying to pass them as one whole variable, I am getting the below error

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot
>   implicitly convert type 'string' to 'string[]'    at
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )    at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0)    at
>   BrandmuscleAutomation.Tests.ChannelBuilder.MarketingFundProgram.CBMain.CBMainCall()
>   in
>   D:\GitAutomation\BrandmuscleAutomation\Tests\ChannelBuilder\MarketingFundProgram\Method.cs:line
>   42

Excel_Stored
[image]

Comment: Try [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21573811/1652222) answer.

Comment: Just because they're stored separated by commas, doesn't mean it's an array. The method is returning a string, but you're trying to put it in a string[]

Comment: What is needed is probably simply split the string, e.g. `exlRange.Value2.ToString().Split(',')`.

Comment: thanks for the inputs. Now when I am printing the output it is providing me with the below output.
Output:
System.String[]